# Where is set [[Value]] for built-in property?

Tags: ecmascript-6

How is setted the property descriptor for the built-in method? For example for isPrototypeOf? I did not find such a place in the specification. Rather found, but there is no description of the attribute [[Value]]. It sounds like this:

> "Every other data property is described in clauses 18 through 26 and
>   in Annex B.2 has the attributes {[[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable] ]:
>   false, [[Configurable]]: true} unless otherwise specified"

Now we know what the other attributes will have, but we do not know what value will be set in [[Value]]. You can say that the value in [[Value]] will be set to the function object and you will be right. However, I want to know by specification where this is the place where for built-in properties is set [[Value]]

Comment: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2018/#sec-method

Comment: @YuryTarabanko ???

Comment: This sections states that method is a function. Sec 19.1.3.3 states `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf` is method. Hence its value is function object. So descriptor's [[Value]] is function. What do you mean by "but we do not know what value will be set in [[Value]]" we know it is function (because it is method) that implements Sec 19.1.3.3 algorithm. What else do you want to know about this value?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko You thrown me the paragraph with the description of function (Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf). But there is not written what will be the value of [[Value]]!

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "But there is not written what will be the value of [[Value]]"? It will be a function. Why do you expect it to be anything else than that? Method is a function that is **a value of a property**. Internal [[Value]] got copied into `descriptor.value` if you do `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, 'isPrototypeOf')`. And it will be a function that hopefully implements the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I want to know by specification where this is the place where for built-in properties is set [[Value]]

The specification doesn't have algorithmic steps for initializing the global objects, which makes sense since they are expected to exist before execution of any code actually begins.

Instead of simply states what structure should exist, so for instance in [19.2.3 Properties of the Function Prototype Object](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object), it simply states

> 19.2.3.1 Function.prototype.apply ( thisArg, argArray )

in the header with the expectation that it is clear that it means the `apply` function is a property of the `%FunctionPrototype%` global object. Given that, there are only two types of properties,

- Accessor properties
- Data properties

Data properties are explicitly simple properties that contain a value. `Function.prototype.apply` doesn't [have `get` or `set` prefix](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-get-regexp.prototype.flags), or [use an `@@` prefix](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-array.prototype-@@iterator)), which means that this statement is specifying a data string-keyed data property. By definition, this means that it is clear that the `[[Value]]` is the function object itself, because there is nowhere else to put it, and `[[Value]]` is the clear correct choice.

The section you linked in [17 ECMAScript Standard Built-in Objects](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object) states

> Every other data property described in clauses 18 through 26 and in Annex B.2 has the attributes { [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true } unless otherwise specified.

is just filling in the rest of the data property fields, since it wouldn't make sense to repeat them for every single method.

Comment: I correctly understand that the specification does not describe [[Value]] for built-in methods?

Comment: Not in formal specification language, I guess. It's extremely clear what the value is though.

Comment: That is, [[Value]] for built-in methods is implicitly equal to the function object?

Comment: It is specified as a property on the prototype. The only place that could be, since we're talking about a data property, is `[[Value]]`.

Comment: So the built-in property of an object in the description of the algorithm is [[Value]]?

Comment: `[[Value]]` is the value of the property, so yes in this case it would be the function. There's nowhere else the function could be stored. If it wasn't the function, there's be nowhere else to put the function, and the whole section would be meaningless.